# which value will get printed?

Tags: c, extern

```
void main()
{
    extern int i;
    printf("%d\n",i);
}
int i;//definetion
int i=35;//definition
```

In the above code `int i` means `i=0;` and `int i=35` means `i=35`.

So which value will get printed any why the compiler is not giving error of `redefinition`?

Comment: That code does not compile. And why are you using `void main()`?!

Comment: There is only one definition.

Comment: @haccks - both are definitions here.

Comment: "int i;" is a declaration

Comment: @KirilKirov; There is a difference between *declaration* and *definition*.

Comment: If `int i` is not definition then why if I remove `int i=35`, the above code prints `0`.

Comment: @haccks - see `3.1 Declarations and definitions` in the standard. `int i;` is a _definition_. `extern int i;` is _declaration_. `int i=35` is _definition_ again.

Comment: @KirilKirov; Which standard C99 or C11?

Comment: @learner it defines `int i` with it's default value `0`.

Comment: @haccks - my bad, I was thinking about C++. `3.1` in the C++ standard. Can't find it in `C`. But I'm still pretty sure it's a definition. Sorry for the misleading.

Comment: if `int i` is not definition then why it is assigning it a default value ie `0`

Comment: Declaration != Definition ! Actually you assigned 35 to i after declare it. So it will print 35.

Comment: That's what the discussion is about. I'm not sure either whether the 0 comes from an actual (hidden) definition of i's value or from the fact that the memory is empty resulting in a 0 value.

Comment: @PeterMiehle `int i;` is a definition according to this popular answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1410632/3156863

Answer (score 3):

In the ansi standard they call `int x;` a "tentative" definition.

This is what ansi standard says:

> A declaration of an identifier for an object that has file scope
>   without an initializer, and without a storage-class specifier or with
>   the storage-class specifier static , constitutes a tentative
>   definition.  If a translation unit contains one or more tentative
>   definitions for an identifier, and the translation unit contains no
>   external definition for that identifier, then the behavior is exactly
>   as if the translation unit contains a file scope declaration of that
>   identifier, with the composite type as of the end of the translation
>   unit, with an initializer equal to 0.

With examples:

```
     int i1 = 1;          /*  definition, external linkage */
     static int i2 = 2;   /*  definition, internal linkage */
     extern int i3 = 3;   /*  definition, external linkage */
     int i4;              /*  tentative definition, external linkage */
     static int i5;       /*  tentative definition, internal linkage */
     int i1;   /*  valid tentative definition, refers to previous */
     int i2;   /*  $3.1.2.2 renders undefined, linkage disagreement */
     int i3;   /*  valid tentative definition, refers to previous */
     int i4;   /*  valid tentative definition, refers to previous */
     int i5;   /*  $3.1.2.2 renders undefined, linkage disagreement */



     extern int i1; /* refers to previous, whose linkage is external */
     extern int i2; /* refers to previous, whose linkage is internal */
     extern int i3; /* refers to previous, whose linkage is external */
     extern int i4; /* refers to previous, whose linkage is external */
     extern int i5; /* refers to previous, whose linkage is internal */
```

In my understanding you can have as many tentative definitions of the same object as you want and at most one definition (with an initializer). If there is no definition, tentative definitions are turned into definition with initializer == 0 at the end of the file.

In other words, the value printed is 35, because there is an initializer.

Comment: if `int i` refers to `int i =35` then we can always replace `extern int i` with `int i`

Comment: Not really. If you place `int i` into a header file it will turn into definition (and reserve a space for the variable) at the end of each file including this header and you will get multiple definition problem during linkage.

Comment: what if I place `int i` before `void main()` and remove `extern int i` from `main()` ....then also the code works

Comment: @learner: If you place `int i;` before main and remove `extern int i;` from main it will work in the same way as now. However all this is not what classical C developer would do. A "normal" developer would put `extern int i;` somewhere in a header file and exactly one `int i = 35;` somethere in a code file.

Comment: how putting `extern int i` in header file will help

Comment: @learner: `extern int i;` will not turn into definition at the end of the file and will never reserve place for the variable while you can use this variable in the whole program. At least in any file including this header.

Comment: but even after adding `extern int i` in header file, it will be required to use `extern int i` in the code as shown in my question>

Comment: @learner: As it was told somewhere: A declaration says "there is such a variable somewhere" and definition says: "here it is!".

Comment: You need to include this header file at the beginning of each code file. In normal case, this header file will contain declarations of many variables not just this one.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45477/discussion-between-marian-and-learner)

Answer (score 1):

from 6.7.5:

> > "A definition of an identifier is a declaration for that identifier that:
> >     — for an object, causes storage to be reserved for that object; ..."

so both `int i;` and `int i = 35;` are definitions (and also declarations since all definitions are declarations).

The difference is that `int i = 35;` also has an explicit initialiser while `int i;` is implicitly initilised to 0 (assuming global therefore static storage duration) only if there isn't an external definition:

from 6.2.9.2:

> > A declaration of an identifier for an object that has file scope without an initializer, and
> >     without a storage-class specifier or with the storage-class specifier static, constitutes a
> >     tentative definition. If a translation unit contains one or more tentative definitions for an
> >     identifier, and the translation unit contains no external definition for that identifier, then
> >     the behavior is exactly as if the translation unit contains a file scope declaration of that
> >     identifier, with the composite type as of the end of the translation unit, with an initializer
> >     equal to 0.

Note that these tentative definitions are not available in c++. (see Appendix C1.2 clause 3.1)

Therefore, in this case the value `35` will be printed since that is the value that `i` is initialised to.